Cumulative subtraction in Pandas Dataframe?
I am looking for a way to achieve column total_diff as shown in this table.
If you take John for example, total trainging_hours is 250. No hours were recorded in month1 to month4, so total_diff remained 250.
In month5 50 hours was recorded so total_diff for month5 is (250-50) = 200, month6(200-60) = 140 and so on.
Same approach for the other names.
enter image description here
I tried below code but did not work as expected.
mask = ~df['month'].isin(['John_Total', 'Amber_Total', 'Barron_Total'])
df.loc[mask, 'total_diff'] = df[mask].groupby("name")['training_hours'].cumsum()
df['total_diff'] = df.groupby('name')['total_diff'].fillna(df['training_hours'])
df

Any help on how to achieve this in python ?

Never ever post a picture of textual data (code, error or data) this is counter productive. Copy paste and format or link instead.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Please don't post pictures of text; instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting (print(df)) or table formatting (print(df.to_markdown()). And please make a smaller example. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

@jlandercy Link? No, we don't want links to external data/code any more than we want pictures of text.

diff = df["training_hours"].where(
    df["month"].str.contains("Total"), -df["training_hours"]
)
df["total_diff"] = diff.groupby(df["name"]).cumsum()

      name         month  training_hours  total_diff
0     John    John_Total             250         250
1     John        month1               0         250
2     John        month2               0         250
3     John        month3               0         250
4     John        month4               0         250
5     John        month5              50         200
6     John        month6              60         140
7     John        month7               0         140
8     John        month8              40         100
9     John        month9              70          30
10    John       month10               0          30
11    John       month11              30           0
12   Amber   Amber_Total             300         300
13   Amber        month1              60         240
14   Amber        month2              70         170
15   Amber        month3               0         170
16   Amber        month4              50         120
17   Amber        month5              20         100
18   Amber        month6              40          60
19   Amber        month7               0          60
20   Amber        month8              50          10
21   Amber        month9              10           0
22   Amber       month10               0           0
23   Amber       month11               0           0
24  Barron  Barron_Total             270         270
25  Barron        month1               0         270
26  Barron        month2              70         200
27  Barron        month3              50         150
28  Barron        month4              50         100
29  Barron        month5               0         100
30  Barron        month6              30          70
31  Barron        month7               0          70
32  Barron        month8              40          30
33  Barron        month9              10          20
34  Barron       month10               5          15
35  Barron       month11              15           0


Example data:
data = {
    'name': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 
             'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 'Amber', 
             'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron', 'Barron'],
    'month': ['John_Total', 'month1', 'month2', 'month3', 'month4', 'month5', 'month6', 'month7', 'month8', 'month9', 'month10', 'month11', 
              'Amber_Total', 'month1', 'month2', 'month3', 'month4', 'month5', 'month6', 'month7', 'month8', 'month9', 'month10', 'month11', 
              'Barron_Total', 'month1', 'month2', 'month3', 'month4', 'month5', 'month6', 'month7', 'month8', 'month9', 'month10', 'month11'],
    'training_hours': [250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 60, 0, 40, 70, 0, 30, 
                       300, 60, 70, 0, 50, 20, 40, 0, 50, 10, 0, 0, 
                       270, 0, 70, 50, 50, 0, 30, 0, 40, 10, 5, 15]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

